# Custom Transformation in Unipager Control

Tags: transformation, kentico, ascx

i don't need default layout of unipager so took the custom transformation. how to render the page numbers in ascx transformation 
my code is following

```html
<div class="container text-center">

<li><a href="/About/Press-Release" aria-label="First"><span aria-hidden="true"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i></span></a></li>
<li><a href="/About/Press-Release" aria-label="Previous"><span aria-hidden="true"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></span></a></li>
<li class="active"><a href="/About/Press-Release">1<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>


<li><a href="/About/Press-Release?page=2" aria-label="Next"><span aria-hidden="true"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></span></a></li>
<li><a href="/About/Press-Release?page=3" aria-label="Last"><span aria-hidden="true"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></span></a></li>

</div>
```

it rendering like [image: My code rendering like]

but it not rendering remaining pages 
Anyone tell me what mistake i did or solution to render next pages like Above[image: Actual design]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uni pager requires a list of transformation

[image]

Result you're getting is exactly what you have in markup.

```
<li><a href="/About/Press-Release" aria-label="First"><span aria-hidden="true"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i></span></a></li>
```

Above line should be First page transformation

```
<li><a href="/About/Press-Release" aria-label="Previous"><span aria-hidden="true"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></span></a></li>
```

Previous page transformation

```
<a href="<%# Eval("PageURL", true) %>"><%# Eval("Page") %></a>
```

Pages transformation (this is what you're missing)

Just continue like this other transformations.

Hope this helps